# Using Foreign Key and References for ON DELETE CASCADE in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I was thinking that these two ways for creating foreign keys are the same

```
CREATE TABLE child1 (
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
parent_id int(11) REFERENCES parent_table(parent_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE child2 (
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
parent_id int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES parent_table(parent_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

but when deleting a record from parent table, the corresponding record in table `child2` will be deleted but NOT that of table `child1`.

Where am I wrong? `REFERENCES` is not enough and we necessary need to write `FOREIGN KEY` to use `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a MySQL *"gotcha"*. The first way does NOT work.

From MySQL docs, [`FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> **Important:**
>
> ... 4 paragraphs below...
>
> Furthermore, InnoDB **does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications”** (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. InnoDB accepts REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification. For other storage engines, MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.

Creating the 2 tables (way 1):

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
parent_id int(11) not null auto_increment,
PRIMARY KEY(parent_id)
);

CREATE TABLE child1 (
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
parent_id int(11) REFERENCES parent_table(parent_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Lets see what is `child1`:

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE child1 ;

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `child1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Where is the `FOREIGN KEY` ? ... Gone with the wind (and without warning)

---

Creating the table `child2` (way 2) works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE child2 (
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
parent_id int(11),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES parent_table(parent_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

> SHOW CREATE TABLE child2 ;

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `child2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `child2_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `parent_table` (`parent_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. I didn't think the syntax for `child1` would even pass when I first looked at this.

One possible reason `child1` fails that you're not explicitly providing a type. Foreign keys need to match type.

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar internal data types inside InnoDB so that they can be compared without a type conversion. The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same. [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

I doubt that's the reason since your DDL is minimalistic and the `parent_id` in the parent table is probably similarly defined.

But disregarding everything else about this question, you *should* use the syntax of `child2` simply because it's more clear and more maintainable.

Comment: The missing type was typo in writing here. The types are all the same in parent, child1, and child2. Yes, I also think that I must use the secure syntax of child2; but still curious to know what the first one does not work ;)